# I missed some research points in some levels, can I replay to get those points?

Tags: starcraft-2

I'm about halfway through the campaign, and realized that I haven't gotten all of the research points from all of the previous missions. I'd really like to get those points (just for completeness)- can I replay the earlier missions and get these points added to my research in the laboratory?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yep! Same goes for the optional goals that reward credits.

Comment: You'll get the difference between what you got the first time through and what you get this time.  If you got one last time, that one will still be available the second time through and you need to collect it in addition to the others to get the full research points available.

Comment: @StrixVaria - Do you still get the research/credits from completing the  second half of the 'optional' missions? Like, completing 'Haven's Fall' after choosing 'Safe Haven'