# StarCraft2: How to get more research points?

Tags: starcraft-2

I've passed campaign once and want to do on the Brutal now.

After passing all 3 first missions I did the "Smash and Grab" - the 1st artifact missions. Upon completion I've discovered that I don't have laboratory available... Then I did "The Evacuation" - the 1st colonist mission.

I've passed the missions twice:
 - 1st time on Brutal level. Here I've collected all 3 Zerg artifacts and used one "re-load";
 - 2nd time on Hard level to get "Sacrifice Nothing" achievement (Complete "The Evacuation" mission on Hard difficulty without losing or salvaging a structure). Actually I've completed "Handled with Care" achievement too (Complete "The Evacuation" mission on Normal difficulty without losing a Transport Truck). And also I've collected all 3 Zerg artefacts on 2nd pass.

When I've visited the laboratory I've discovered that I have 4 Protoss research points and 6 (!) Zerg points...

Question: What is a source of additional 3 Zerg points? As far as I know, till the end of all researches done no new research points are available when missions are completed.

Am I correct? Or each mission pass gives you all available missions research points?

P.S. Here is a similar question ([I missed some research points in some levels, can I replay to get those points?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5695/i-missed-some-research-points-in-some-levels-can-i-replay-to-get-those-points)), but it's answer is not clear for me.

Comment: Go to the bridge and look in your mission archives. Each mission lists how much research you get for it. Perhaps it's listed there? If not it could be a bug.

Comment: Why you didn't make it as answer, I would accept it. Actually, on the bridge I have 3/3 for that mission, and totally in laboratory I still have 6 points... Don't know how to exploit that though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a bug for now...

Answer (score 2):

If you're going back and RE-playing the missions, it'll take the research from the mission where you got the most research. So even if you did the normal mission and got 4 points, and then did the brutal mission and got 0 points, 4 points will be available in the next mission.

It won't double up though. I'm pretty sure about this: I did the whole campaign on hard, then went back and replayed every mission on brutal, and I know I didn't get *extra* research.

Answer (score 1):

You are talking about a mission that is an option mission.  You have the option of either saving the colony or purging it, whichever direction you choose first will be the only available research points you can earn, regardless of going back and replaying both mission possibilities.  If you chose the zerg research, you cant go back and replay to earn the protoss research.  You either have to load a save of the campaign before you made the decision or start a new campaign.  Note, loading a previous game will lose any progress in the campaign, after the save point, however, achievements earned after the save point will still show as earned on your profile, but may not appear in your campaign.  When all else fails, make detailed saves often, and check your profile when searching for achievements left to earn.

Note: during the media blitz level, destroying a civilian building in the bottom right corner unlocks the zeratul missions, allowing for 6 more research points, 3z 3p.  Once you destroy the building, grab the files, finish the level, go the the laboratory and you will see a crystal in the bottom left.

Note: once you start the final missions on char, you cannot unlock the zeratul missions, load a previous save before going to char and start from there, you will have to replay some stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Although it doesn't seem to be indicated on [Liquipedia](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Main_Page), I believe one of the Mar Sara missions gives you the extra three zerg points you are confused about.

Comment: It seems to be true, but Mar Sara missions on the bridge doesn't show earned research points